# Dynamic website scraping not picking items in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I want to site **scrape** following web page. However, dynamic website scraping libraries like selenium and puppeteersharp do not pick up items shown on the table of this page (see image).

https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/trade-our-cash-market/todays-announcements

None of the above libs list hrefs under Headline column, although if I try to save a screenshot of this page I can see few table rows.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

why aren't these well established libs not working on this page?

[image]

Comment: https://www.asx.com.au/asx/v2/statistics/todayAnns.do have you tried directly scraping from this page?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' (and scrapped, scrapper, scrapping) means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Comment: thanks this is a great idea @Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you trying to scrape here is inside iframe.
To access it you have to switch to that iframe.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522364/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-web-content-inside-iframes) example how to switch to iframe with BeautifulSoup.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825722/scraping-iframe-using-selenium) example with Selenium scraping inside iframe.
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741745/how-to-fill-a-form-inside-an-iframe-with-puppeteer-sharp) with puppeteersharp

Comment: Thanks for your time. Lee above suggested a simpler approach.

Comment: @Patola He found a workaround for that specific site while I tried to show you the way that will work for any data contained inside the iframe